# Referencing/citing does not work

Tags: citing, apacite

I have huge troubles with citing in LaTeX. Whatever I try it just does not work.

So, first of all I have my tex file. Then I created a BibTex file, saved it as "`Abschlusslit.bib`" and saved it in the same file as my tex-file.

This is my BibTex file:

```
@book{Alexandrowicz2013,
    author = {Alexandrowicz, R. W.},
    title = {{R in 10 Schritten. Eine Einführung in die statistische Programmierumgebung}},
    year = {2013},
    publisher = {Facultas},
    address = {Wien},
}
```

and this is my tex file:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Abschlusslit}
Tau vom Boden, drohte ihnen damit und hielt sie dadurch
von dem Sprunge ab  \cite{Alexandrowicz2013}. 
\end{document}
```

---

It does not seem to find the reference, only a question mark appears in the place where the reference should come. It just gives me a lot of error messages. 
Like "undefined control sequence" and it opens up a .bbl document but I don't know what that is. 
The .bbl document looks like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem [\protect \citeauthoryear {%
Frijters%
\ \BBA {} Beatton%
}{%
Frijters%
\ \BBA {} Beatton%
}{%
{\protect \APACyear {{\protect \bibnodate {}}}}%
}]{%
FrijtersBeatton}
\APACinsertmetastar {%
FrijtersBeatton}%
\begin{APACrefauthors}%
Frijters, P.%
\BCBT {}\ \BBA {} Beatton, T.%
\end{APACrefauthors}%
\unskip\
\newblock
\APACrefYearMonthDay{{\protect \bibnodate {}}}{}{}.
\newblock
{\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle {The mystery of the U-shaped relationship between
  happiness and age} {The mystery of the u-shaped relationship between
  happiness and age}.{\BBCQ}
\newblock
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}
\end{thebibliography}
```

---

Should I delete it? Has anyone of you encountered the same problem and can help me.

Comment: If you want to use the style `apacite` (for APA compliant citations) you must also load the `apacite` package (which is probably incompatible with `cite`): Replace `\usepackage{cite}` with `\usepackage{apacite}`.

Comment: If you don't need full APA compliance, you could use something like `\bibliographstyle{apalike}` or `\bibliographystyle{plain}` instead or load `natbib` instead of `cite` and use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but you should clean your MWE to make them as small as possible. I don't think `geometry`, `multicol` and `setspace`are useful for this case.

Answer (score 1):

For the `apacite` bibliography style in old bibtex you *must* also use the `apacite` **package**,

```
\usepackage{multicol,apacite}
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and your answers. As suggested, I have replaced \usepackage{cite} with \usepackage{multicol,apacite}. Unfortunately it still does not work. There are no error messages this time but the question marks remain. Obviously, there is no communication between the bib and the tex file. kind regards, Helena

Comment: Did you run `latex` -- `bibtex` (or `biber` if you use `biblatex`) -- `latex` agein on your document? You need to call `latex` to create your document and then call `bibtex` to parse the referenced keys and then `latex` again to create the final text with references and bibliography.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried them out.
The previous error messages have disappeared and now I get different ones:

bbl. file: Undefined control sequence. \bibitem{Alex2013}

bbl.file: You can't use `\relax' after \the. \bibitem{Alex2013}

tex. file: No \author given.

And lots of 

Underfull \hbox (badness 5417) in paragraph. 

I guess it is very difficult for you to follow back where the errors come from but I am happy with any kind of help. I have spent hours and hours reading in forums and trying to figure it out but nothing seems to work.